# Как добавить css-класс в html для всех элементов определенного класса с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, dom, scss

Необходимо, чтобы при клике добавлялся класс "general-info__grid-view".
В моём коде необходимый класс добавляется только к первому параграфу, а нужно, чтобы добавлялся ко всем параграфам. Мой код:

```js
document.getElementById("grid").onclick = function() {
  document.body.querySelector(".general-info__description").classList.
  remove("general-info__grid-none");
  document.body.querySelector(".general-info__description").classList.
  add("general-info__grid-view");
}
```

```css
.general-info__grid-none {
  display: none;
}

.general-info__grid-view {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">grid</div>
<div class="general-info__records-container">
  <p class="general-info__description general-info__grid-none">Covering:</p>
</div>
<div class="general-info__records-container">
  <p class="general-info__description general-info__grid-none">Type:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("grid").onclick = function () {

var generalInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".general-info__description");

    generalInfo.forEach(function(generalInfo) {
        generalInfo.classList.add("general-info__grid-view");
    });
};
```

Comment: Зачем давать такой-же ответ, как и дал `Darth`. Бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает только один элемент. Вам нужен [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.getElementById("grid").onclick = function() {
  [...document.body.querySelectorAll(".general-info__description")].forEach(el => {
    el.classList.remove("general-info__grid-none");
    el.classList.add("general-info__grid-view");
  });
}
```

```css
.general-info__grid-none {
  display: none;
}

.general-info__grid-view {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">grid</div>
<div class="general-info__records-container">
  <p class="general-info__description general-info__grid-none">Covering:</p>
</div>
<div class="general-info__records-container">
  <p class="general-info__description general-info__grid-none">Type:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, совсем не работает; никаких изменений при клике

Comment: @Serge, а в примере почему работает? Посмотри  консоль, что сообщает...