# Как после каждого <p> добавлять <hr>? С обычным JS

Tags: javascript, for

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  var element = document.createElement('hr');
  p.append(element);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, suscipit dolorem fugiat aut quasi dolore nihil minima alias odio excepturi voluptas officia eaque nobis pariatur vel labore tempore ut! Quas, libero labore temporibus explicabo quae unde corrupti pariatur ratione? A.</p>
  <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, tempore quos veritatis architecto asperiores at dolor dolorum. Eius perspiciatis sit eveniet laboriosam aspernatur. Delectus, a suscipit. Facere, quos. Commodi sapiente iure quo. Facere, incidunt omnis. Quisquam magnam fugit ipsum totam.</p>
  <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo recusandae quaerat natus eius libero blanditiis, quia, exercitationem nesciunt quis dolores commodi perferendis veniam laborum totam nostrum laudantium similique deserunt? Culpa, nihil sapiente! Ullam autem libero magni accusantium necessitatibus ipsa maxime?</p>
</article>
```

Comment: почему бы это не сделать при помощи, css добавив border?

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781641/256824

Comment: @splash58 знаю но именно с помощью Js  мне нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня работает вот так (обратите внимание на
`querySelectorAll`):

```xhtml
<article>
  <h3>Header 1</h3>
  <p>Text 1</p>
  <h3>Header 2</h3>
  <p>Text 2</p>
  <h3>Header 3</h3>
  <p>Text 3</p>
</article>
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(
    (p) => p.parentNode.insertBefore(
      document.createElement('hr'),
      p.nextSibling,
    )
  );
</script>
```

Comment: @Leks  Вы точно попробовали мою последнюю правку?  Там сначала было `append`, а потом я исправил на `insertBefore` с `p.nextSipling`.

Comment: а не норм это я сам накосячил  до Вас :((

Comment: @Ainar-G Все работает спасибо, мне нужно было только поставить querySelectorAll

Comment: @IbragimMadiyarov  Не за что.  Я вижу у вас в профиле, что вы ещё не приняли ни одного ответа.  Ответы, которые вам помогли, принято поощрять и принимать, нажав галочку слева от вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for ( let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  let element = document.createElement('hr');
  p[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<hr>');
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, suscipit dolorem fugiat aut quasi dolore nihil minima alias odio excepturi voluptas officia eaque nobis pariatur vel labore tempore ut! Quas, libero labore temporibus explicabo quae unde corrupti pariatur ratione? A.</p>
  <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, tempore quos veritatis architecto asperiores at dolor dolorum. Eius perspiciatis sit eveniet laboriosam aspernatur. Delectus, a suscipit. Facere, quos. Commodi sapiente iure quo. Facere, incidunt omnis. Quisquam magnam fugit ipsum totam.</p>
  <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo recusandae quaerat natus eius libero blanditiis, quia, exercitationem nesciunt quis dolores commodi perferendis veniam laborum totam nostrum laudantium similique deserunt? Culpa, nihil sapiente! Ullam autem libero magni accusantium necessitatibus ipsa maxime?</p>
</article>
```

```js
const p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for ( let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  let element = document.createElement('hr');
  p[i].after(element)
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, suscipit dolorem fugiat aut quasi dolore nihil minima alias odio excepturi voluptas officia eaque nobis pariatur vel labore tempore ut! Quas, libero labore temporibus explicabo quae unde corrupti pariatur ratione? A.</p>
  <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, tempore quos veritatis architecto asperiores at dolor dolorum. Eius perspiciatis sit eveniet laboriosam aspernatur. Delectus, a suscipit. Facere, quos. Commodi sapiente iure quo. Facere, incidunt omnis. Quisquam magnam fugit ipsum totam.</p>
  <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo recusandae quaerat natus eius libero blanditiis, quia, exercitationem nesciunt quis dolores commodi perferendis veniam laborum totam nostrum laudantium similique deserunt? Culpa, nihil sapiente! Ullam autem libero magni accusantium necessitatibus ipsa maxime?</p>
</article>
```

Comment: @Leks так тоже не получается

Comment: да даже с After

Comment: Благодарю!! Вам

Comment: все еще не получается :(

Answer (score 0):

Можно не выеживаться с js ,а сделать на css:

```css
p.with-hr {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
  <p class="with-hr"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, suscipit dolorem fugiat aut quasi dolore nihil minima alias odio excepturi voluptas officia eaque nobis pariatur vel labore tempore ut! Quas, libero labore temporibus explicabo quae unde corrupti pariatur ratione? A.</p>
  <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
  <p class="with-hr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, tempore quos veritatis architecto asperiores at dolor dolorum. Eius perspiciatis sit eveniet laboriosam aspernatur. Delectus, a suscipit. Facere, quos. Commodi sapiente iure quo. Facere, incidunt omnis. Quisquam magnam fugit ipsum totam.</p>
  <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo recusandae quaerat natus eius libero blanditiis, quia, exercitationem nesciunt quis dolores commodi perferendis veniam laborum totam nostrum laudantium similique deserunt? Culpa, nihil sapiente! Ullam autem libero magni accusantium necessitatibus ipsa maxime?</p>
</article>
```